# Facebook login has become unstable

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have been using Facebook login (PHP SDK) for a website for months without problems.
Since a few days, we are experiencing problems.

Here is the code

```
    $fbconfig['appid' ]     = "...";
    $fbconfig['secret']     = "...";
    $fbconfig['baseurl']    = "myurl/index.php";

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
      'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));

    $user       = $facebook->getUser();

    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'email,user_likes,user_birthday',
                'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
            )
    );

    $logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(
            array(
                'next'  => $fbconfig['baseurl'].'?f=logout'
            )
    );
    if ($user) {
     ....try {
                $fb_user_infos_ar = $facebook->api('/me');
        }

        catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

            $facebook->destroySession();
            $user = null;
        }
    }

if (isset($fb_user_infos_ar)){
do something...
}
else{
show facebook login button
}
```

The problem we are experiencing is that the login seems to work, but after a while (most of the time even after a few seconds) the user is not recognized anymore as logged into facebook ($user is 0 and the login button is showed).

Has there been any change in the last few days to facebook rules or browsers that can explain this behavior? I have tried with both firefox and chrome with the same result.
Since my PHP sdk was a few months old, I also tried with the very latest one with the same result. I also noticed that in the last version examples, "base_url" is not mentioned anymore, do you know why?

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS**

After some hints coming from the comments, I have tried to debug what is happening; it seems that the token doesn't become invalid; in fact when I log-in again I still get a token generated hours before.

For some reason, however, sometime the user is considered NOT LOGGED (basically $facebook->getUser() is false) even if he is LOGGED.

One of the reason, as complex857 suggested, could be that facebook is having problems in talking with my site; in the last days I actually noticed a general performances loss in the site and after a debugging session today, I can say that the performances loss appears when there is a facebook activity involved.
In particular I measured the execution time of this single instruction:

```
$fb_user_infos_ar = $facebook->api('/me');
```

and it is about 5 seconds; I have no idea how long it took before but I guess is too much; what do you think?

About possible cookies problem, what should I check?

**EDIT 2 after answer**

More details: if there are problems during the API call (catch part) I used to destroy the facebook session with

```
$facebook->destroySession();
```

and that's why the user logged out. Sometime it is actually not needed to destroy the session (e.g. if there is a timeout due to a network problem) so I should handle the exception according to the error.

As far as I have understood, the piece of code that Andy Jones provided

```
echo "error code = " . $e->getCode() . " error = " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
```

works fine for a CURL error but not for other kind of errors (e.g. token expired). For example if I print out the exception when the token is invalid due to password change I get:

> FacebookApiException Object (
>       [result:protected] => Array
>           (
>               [error] => Array
>                   (
>                       [message] => Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the
>   password.
>                       [type] => OAuthException
>                       [code] => 190
>                       [error_subcode] => 460
>                   )
>
> ```
>     )
>
> [message:protected] => Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.
> [string:Exception:private] => 
> [code:protected] => 0 ....
> ```

$e->getCode() just give me 0 instead of 190.

Here is the list of the errors: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/ I think that a simple way to handle the process in my specific case would be: destroy the facebook session if the code is 190 or 102, otherwise try to repeat the operation. What do you think and which would be the best practice piece of code to handle this in a general way?

Another question: while logging the exceptions with $e->getMessage() I got
"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password."
but I'm sure that for the user I was using at the time (my own) I haven't changed the facebook password. How can this happen? Is the same message produced even in other cases (e.g. when a token is at its natural expiration date)?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to save an access token while its valid and submit to the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) once it seem to go bad. What does it tell about it?

Comment: It just says
APP ID: myappid

and nothing else

Comment: Sorry, that was for a (I think) already expired token. With a valid one I get

Appi id ..
user id ...
Issued 1383249851 (21 hours ago)
Expires 1388433851 (in about 2 months)
Valid True
Origin Web
Scopes email, read_stream, user_birthday, user_friends, user_likes, user_status

Comment: Sounds like then the tokens should be ok, maybe they are not reaching your backend. I'm really just guessing here, but try to check if your session storage  (by default files on disk) and the cookies facebook and php session lib sets up are working properly.

Comment: A user reported this
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
In the firefox console... could this be related? The site also uses APIs from another service which, in turn, uses facebook login so this message could be related to that service. I don't see the message in my console.
Furthermore, I can see from a PING to the site, that there are some packets lost.

Comment: I'm not sure but worth to fix it non the less. I don't think it's related to anything else other than what the error message said (calling js sdk functions before `FB.init()`).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have edited the question with more details about what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that may go wrong and you should examine the underlying cause and take appropriate action...

```
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  $facebook->destroySession();
  $user = null;
}
```

Currently you're simply destroying the session and moving on. However, the exception has lots of wonderful data. From `FacebookBase.php`, you'll find in the function `makeRequest` where it throws the `FacebookAPIException`.

```
$e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error' => array(
    'message' => curl_error($ch),
    'type' => 'CurlException',
    )));
throw $e;
```

Most importantly, you want to examine the cURL error code from `curl_errno` and the human readable message from `curl_error`. You may do this by...

```
echo "error code = " . $e->getCode() . " error = " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
```

Curl will tell you what went wrong with the [explanation of the error code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html). For some of the more common errors, (6 = no resolve host, 7 = no connect, 28 = timeout), this may indicate a problem with your network connection, Facebook, or somewhere in between. Or the Facebook API could simply be busy and not responding quickly. The most usual response is simply try again.

If you're seeing an error code of 0 (zero) - no error - this means that Facebook the call worked correctly, but Facebook simply returned no data. This is an error with Facebook.

If you're seeing other errors, take a look at the [explanation of error codes](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), and go from there.

The Facebook Graph API makes no guarantees on up-time. You should consider caching as much as possible on your end and handle errors as they arise. I know this is more work for the programmer, however this is the inter-connected world to which we're moving.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; there was an error log procedure but for some reason it has been removed a few days ago; anyway I accepted your answer because it gave me the right direction to move in; however, I still have some doubts about it so I have edited again the question wit more details.